# Is solving a quadratic equation using Turing machine impossible?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I've just started Algorithms at university. There's a task to write an algorithm for a Turing machine to solve quadratic equations. The task doesn't specify if it's x^2+bx+c or ax^2+bx+c. I've searched whole bunch of information over Russian and English Internet.

I did find articles, which say it's not possible because we've got real numbers A, B, C. Please confirm if that's true. I may not get it correct.. But I think that's impossible. I still don't know how to prove my thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess the instructor assumed using only naturals in this problem.

Comment: The question is ill-posed. What does it mean to solve a quadratic? What is the input, and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not clear enough. Turing Machines can or cannot solve problems if those problems are languages, that means, sets of strings over a finite alphabet. You cannot represent all reals in this way, so it is not even a problem that a TM could even attempt to solve. In the same fashion that world hunger is not a problem in the precise sense that a computational complexity requires it to be.

The problem is obviously solvable if you define it as the sets of words that encode three rational numbers a, b and c in a standard way.  How do you solve this? Well, the construction of the machine that does this is rather complicated, but you know how to do this in let's say, Python, right? So you can always compile your Python code into a TM.